# Struts 2 array copy in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2

For copy value to next action used following syntax

```
<s:hidden name="formRow.value" value="%{formRow.value}" />
```

What syntax should I use to copy whole array of objects with thier fields? I've tried such apprach:

```
<s:iterator var="entry" value="%{formRow.myArray}" status="stat">
    <s:hidden name="formRow.myArray[#stat.index].val1" value="%{entry.val1}"/>
    <s:hidden name="formRow.myArray[#stat.index].val2" value="%{entry.val2}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

but while form submitting, **formRow.myArray** still empty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `value` attribute is not actually needed, `name` is enough. Try this:

```
<s:iterator value="formRow.myArray" status="stat">
   <s:hidden name="formRow.myArray[%{#stat.index}].val1"/>
   <s:hidden name="formRow.myArray[%{#stat.index}].val2"/>
</s:iterator>
```